# How to capture groups of strings with indentation?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to capture every if-construct in this string as a single one

```
if a > b
    do this
    do that
    if a == c
        do this
        do that
```

I would like to have a match for

```
if a > b
    do this
    do that
```

and

```
    if a == c
        do this
        do that
```

What I have so far doesn't seperate between new if-constructs

```
if(\W+\w+)+\n\t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(\s*if[\s\S]+?)(?=^\s*if|\z)
```

in `MULTILINE` mode.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dF4rU7/1)

`[\s\S]+` will match 1 more characters **including newlines** and `(?=^\s*if|\z)` is a lookahead that will make sure to assert that next to current match is another `if` block or end of input.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain this rather complex piece?

Comment: Yes I have updated it with some explanation. Also take a look at linked demo for more explanation in the left panel.

Comment: Yes it did! Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're trying to do, you should consider writing a parser. It'll keep things simpler for you in the long run.

If you insist on using a regex, well...

```
^([ ]*)if.+\r?\n(\1[ ]+).+(?:\r?\n\2(?!if).+)*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lH0cE6/1)

Usage:

```
var re = new Regex(@"^([ ]*)if.+\r?\n(\1[ ]+).+(?:\r?\n\2(?!if).+)*", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Let's split it up into pieces:

- `^([ ]*)if.+\r?\n` captures a first `if` with leading spaces until a line break
- `(\1[ ]+).+` captures the next line. It requires *more* spaces (so it's indented).
- `(?:\r?\n\2(?!if).+)*` captures the next lines up until the next `if`. It requires the *same* amount of spaces as the first line after the `if`.